# How can I determine why a users password change did not succeed?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, password

I've set up a new domain user account for one of our client's employees. I randomly generated a password for the user account and set it up so the user has to change the password on first log in. We use the [default Windows Server 2008 R2 password policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786468(v=ws.10).aspx).

Now I'm on the phone with said user, tell the user the temporary password, explain the password rules and they're unable to change the password. The new password is simply rejected.

I explain the password rules again and the user assures me that the password complies with those rules. So I try to log in to the account myself, use my own custom password as the new password and it works right away.

This suggests to me that the user is incorrectly assuming that the password complies with the password policy but is unable to see the mistake.

Without asking the user for their password, how can I determine what the problem with their password is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send them a written copy of the rules, because they're clearly failing to understand what they are. You can also ask them for the password that they're trying, and just have them make another one, once they understand what the rules are.

Comment: I was hoping that password change failures are logged somewhere (I couldn't find anything) or that a specific tool exists that allows the user to test their password.

Comment: I really think the only "tool" is their reading comprehension and ability to discern the current state of CAPS LOCK.

Answer (score 1):

Generally password policies are the main attributes of an organization.At your case do check at the security policies you assign to the user.Once you check in to the rights of the user there after you can then call upon the user and say the instructions again.

Generally today at market there are many third party tools are also available to manage the active directory password reset policy.There are many of the tools who can manage the password on the behalf of user itself also.Admin just by giving the rights to the user, user can change it password itself only.